# Simple node.js http request proxy giving me a gzip error

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers, gzip

I am using the below code, to start a server that accepts http requests, and then forwards them to an https api, then relay the response.

I have a problem in that the api gives a 'Content-Encoding: gzip' response, which seems to be causing me trouble.

If I don't relay the gzip response header, the C# code I'm testing gets a response that is just random symbols, the compressed data I assume, as does Postman. When I do include as per my example below, I get StatusCode 0: "The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream."

I've tried passing the response headers back as:

res.writeHead(cres.statusCode, cres.headers});

But that just seems to result in the jumbled output again. How can I fix this?

````
const https = require('https')
const port = 55555

const requestHandler = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.url)

  var options = {
    host:   'my.api.com',
    path:   '/7f308b16-d165-4062-b00f-76970783442e'+req.url,
    path:   req.url,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: req.headers
  };

  var json = '';

  var creq = https.request(options, function(cres) {

    // set encoding
    cres.setEncoding('utf8');

    // wait for data
    cres.on('data', function(chunk){
      console.log('data: '+chunk);
      json += chunk;
    });

    cres.on('close', function(){
      console.log('close: '+cres.statusCode);
      res.writeHead(cres.statusCode);
      res.end();
    });

    cres.on('end', function(){
      console.log('end: '+json.toString());
      console.log(res.headers)
      res.writeHead(cres.statusCode, {'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Type':'text/json; charset=utf-8', 'Cache-Control':'private'  });
      res.end(json);
    });

  }).on('error', function(e) {
    // we got an error, return 500 error to client and log error
    console.log(e.message);
    res.writeHead(500);
    res.end();
  });

  creq.end();
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)

server.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})```
````

Comment: can you get headers from `cres`?

Comment: I've tried setting the responss headers as cres.headers, but it doens't seem to contain the Content-Encoding: gzip header, it's possible it's only giving me the request headers from cres, I can't see anything about getting repsonse headers specifically.